# Error al instalar mysql-server en Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mysql, linux

Qué tal, cuando hago `sudo apt install mysql-server` me devuelve esto:

https://gist.github.com/LautaroLobo12/a29097b1ec524e192af94838ba1bf073

Y luego cualquier cosa que haga me tira error. No lo puedo configurar ni conectarme al localhost ni nada. Probé desinstalarlo y volverlo a instalar pero me devuelve lo mismo.

Si luego de tratar de instalarlo corro `sudo mysql_secure_installation` (que sería el paso siguiente luego de instalar mysql-server), devuelve:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

¿Puede ser que al desinstalarlo previamente quedó algún archivo suelto y por eso me tira error?

Tengo que usarlo en un proyecto en .net y bueno, estoy trabado por esto.

edit: agrego el resultado de correr `systemctl status mysql.service`, por si sirve:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-03-28 17:18:00 -03; 3min 40s ago
  Process: 14443 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mar 28 17:18:00 pop-os systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
mar 28 17:18:00 pop-os systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
mar 28 17:18:00 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
mar 28 17:18:00 pop-os systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 28 17:18:00 pop-os systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 28 17:18:00 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: ¿Haz intentado con un `sudo apt purge mysql-server` y luego volver a instalar y luego un `sudo service mysql restart`?

Comment: Ya al correr el primer comando me tira error: `dpkg: error al procesar el paquete mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete mysql-server-5.7 script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 2
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Como eso es tema de otra pregunta, espero que no nos regañen por discutir eso en los comentarios. Intenta con esto:
 `sudo apt purge mysql* && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, reinicia tu máquina y luego trata de reinstalar `mysql-server`.

Comment: O si puedes, pon ese problema en una publicación nueva.

Comment: Hola @Cuauhtli, funcionó! Muchas gracias! Si quieres pon el código en un a respuesta y te la marco como correcta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como tu error parece por un problema de dependencias y de archivos de configuración (probablemente por una mala reinstalación) entonces se me ocurre que podrías utilizar lo siguiente:

```
sudo apt purge mysql* 
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt autoclean 
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Y luego reinstalar `mysql-server`:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server -y
```

Ya después de esto puedes correr el servidor con:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

#### Un poco de explicación.

- `apt purge` es semejante a `apt remove` salvo que el primero elimina ciertos archivos de configuración y no el segundo (que los deja intactos).
- `apt autoremove` elimina los paquetes que fueron instalados para satisfacer las dependencias de otros paquetes pero que ahora ya no son requeridos.
- `apt autoclean` limpia el repositorio local de archivos de paquetes recuperados que ya no van a ser utilizados.
- `apt dist-upgrade` actualiza y maneja "inteligentemente" las dependencias cambiantes con nuevas versiones de paquetes.

Todo esto es una paráfrasis de lo que puedes encontrar en `apt-get(8)` en los respectivos apartados.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que no tengas el servicio levantado.

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: Corrí ese código y me tira un error que tiene solución aparente [aquí](http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/failed-to-restart-mysql-service-unit-mysql-service-is-masked/). Hice lo que decía ahí y en el último paso obtengo otro error: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`. Si corro de nuevo el código que pusiste, pues devuelve lo mismo como es de esperar.

Comment: Haz un backup de **/var/lib/mysql**, elimina todo menos la carpeta mysql, prueba con este comando `sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/var/lib/mysql/` e intenta levantar el servicio de nuevo

Comment: Tengo 4 carpetas de mysql en /var/lib/: mysql, mysql-files, mysql-keyring y mysql-upgrade, todas vacías. Corrí ese código y me devolvió un error `unknown variable 'ldata=/var/lib/mysql/'`, así que usé --datadir. El resultado fue `2020-03-28 17:56:05 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
2020-03-28 17:57:51 [WARNING] The bootstrap log isn't empty:
2020-03-28 17:57:51 [WARNING] 2020-03-28T20:56:06.029200Z 0 [Warning] --bootstrap is deprecated. Please consider using --initialize instead`.

Comment: Luego, al tipear mysql devuelve `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. A pesar de que aún no lo logro resolver, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder :)